# SQL запрос последние строки по ID пользователей (в MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет, задача такая, умишка у меня не хватает
Дана таблица в базе:

1. ID
2. USER_ID
3. PRICE
4. DATE - Дата в формате UNIXTIME (просто INTEGER)

**Задача:**

вывести последние ставки пользователей, результатом должны быть две строки с последними ставками этих пользователей:

- первая строка = последняя ставка одного пользователя,
- вторая соотв. второго.

**Суть задачи:** сформировать оптимальный mySQL-запрос (по скорости, учитывая что за раз может быть тысячи таких запросов на одной странице)
Спасибо

Comment: А почему "две строки"? Всего два пользователя? Или надо для каждого пользователя вывести две записи: последняя и предпоследняя ставка? По описанию - одна запись на пользователя, но не понятно почему именно две строки

Comment: @BOPOH может, кто с кем соревнуется в ставках. вообще-то, выглядит разумено

Comment: @splash58, сейчас я просто пытаюсь понять задачу. Если две записи, т.к. два пользователя - это одно, если две последние ставки каждого пользователя - это другое, если пользователей много, но надо вывести две последние записи от разных пользователей - это третье

Comment: конечно, это плохой аргумент, но я понимаю хзадачу как 3 :)

Comment: @splash58, если задача - это 3, то тогда будет вопрос: а как ставки делаются? Может ли один и тот же человек сделать две ставки подряд? Если это аукцион и он не оканчивается по времени, то логично что делать ставку два раза нельзя, тогда будет просто сортировка по дате и выборка двух записей. Если один человек может сделать подряд несколько ставок, тогда подойдет вариант из ответа (есть и другие варианты, но и этот неплохой)

Comment: то что я написал, может совсем плохо по эфективности, но все равно, сколько раз встречается один и тот же user_id

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так, не так уж оптимальная но рабочая.

```
select * 
   from <таблица>
where (USER_ID, DATE) in
(
  select USER_ID, max(DATE) from content group by USER_ID  
)
```

для оптимизации лучще отдельнцю таблицу сделать с только последними строками

Comment: Если id - auto_increment, то не сработает, т.к. это будет равносильно `select * from table`

Comment: да согласен, ошибся с колонками

Comment: кажись я сам нагуглил, всем спасибо

SELECT u.`user_id`, u.`price`, u.`date`
FROM `users` u JOIN
(SELECT `user_id`, max(`date`) as `mtime` FROM `users` GROUP BY `user_id`) as t1 
ON u.`user_id`= t1.`user_id` AND u.`date` = t1.`mtime`;